# Listbox isn't populating with Data

Tags: c#, listbox

I have set up a listbox called lboxsupplier, i have also created a data adapter which i then used to populate the supplier listbox. When i run the form the listbox is empty. I want the listbox to populate with supplier ID and company which i will then click on to populate another listbox with products.

```
Namespace Pennyburn_Greg
{
public partial class FormProcess : Form
{
    SqlDataAdapter daSupplier;
    DataSet dsPennyburnGreg = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmdSupplierDetails;
    SqlCommandBuilder cmdBSupplier;
    DataRow drSupplier;
    String connstr, sqlSupplier;

    public FormProcess()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



private void FormProcess_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connstr = @"Data Source= arlene-pc; Initial Catalog= PennyburnGreg; Integrated Security=True";

    //dataAdapter for supplier listbox

        sqlSupplier = @"Select* from Supplier";
        conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        cmdSupplierDetails = new SqlCommand(sqlSupplier, conn);
        daSupplier = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSupplierDetails);
        daSupplier.FillSchema(dsPennyburnGreg, SchemaType.Source, "Supplier");
}
    private void filllboxsupplier(string str)
    {
        daSupplier.Fill(dsPennyburnGreg, "Supplier");
        lboxsupplier.DataSource = dsPennyburnGreg.Tables["Supplier"];
        lboxsupplier.DisplayMember = "Company";
        lboxsupplier.ValueMember = "SupplierID";


    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your posted code is confusing. Not sure what you are trying actually?

Comment: I am trying to get the name of the company and supplierID from my supplier table and get them to appear in the listbox

Comment: Can you explain why you add a parameter when your query doesn't require any?

Comment: First thing to do is set a break point after your method call to `Fill` and make sure data is being returned. Next thing to do is clean up your code. Your `SqlDataAdapter`, `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, etc...should all be local variables, not class wide variables and they should all be surrounded with `using` statements.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why are you calling `FillSchema`, rather should be calling `Fill` method to get the data, like

```
daSupplier.Fill(dsPennyburnGreg, "Supplier");
```

Once you have the dataset filled, then in your `FormProcess_Load()` you can add the dataset as datasource to the listbox like

```
lboxsupplier.DataSource = dsPennyburnGreg.Tables["Supplier"]
```

Comment: I have now edited my code to this but it still isn't populating

Comment: Have you set the `DisplayMember` and `Valuemember`? Also, do check whether the datatable present in dataset is not empty. This shouls work fine.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is loosely couple your UI and data a little bit. Try this code:

```
// Returns a DataTable of ALL suppliers
private DataTable GetSuppliers()
{
    return GetSuppliers(0);
}

// Returns a DataTable of the given supplier
private DataTable GetSuppliers(int supplierId)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlCommand())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source= arlene-pc; Initial Catalog= PennyburnGreg; Integrated Security=True";
        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Connection = connection;

            if (supplierId == 0)
            { 
                command.commandText = "SELECT * FROM Supplier";
            }
            else
            {
                command.commandText = "SELECT * FROM Supplier WHERE SupplierId=@id";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", supplierId);
            }
            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                using (var ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                    adapter.Fill(ds);

                    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                        return ds.Tables[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And now you can just do this:

```
lboxsupplier.DataSource = GetSuppliers(int.Parse(lboxsupplier.SelectedValue));
lboxsupplier.DisplayMember = "Company";
lboxsupplier.ValueMember = "SupplierID";
```

Or if you need all Suppliers, just do this:

```
lboxsupplier.DataSource = GetSuppliers();
lboxsupplier.DisplayMember = "Company";
lboxsupplier.ValueMember = "SupplierID";
```

This code will provide some separation. This is still not ideal, but beats what you had.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the listbox control in `FormProcess_Load`, so it will be empty when it first loads. I'm assuming you have `lboxsupplier_Click` bound to the `Click` event of `lboxsupplier`? If so, then you'll need to click on that listbox before it will populate the Dataset (which is a very odd user experience, but if that's truly what you need...). If `lboxsupplier_Click` isn't an event handler, then you're going to have to manually call it.

If it still isn't populating, then try running your query against the database directly, and make sure that it returns data and has columns named "Company" and "SupplierID"